# Google analytics 4 events sometimes not arriving

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am tracking purchases on a site in google analytics by sending a custom event from JavaScript to Google Tag Manager on the "successful purchase" page. Most of the time this works perfectly, but in some cases it seems the event just doesn't arrive to Google Analytics.

Initially I thought that maybe visiting the success page couldn't be relied on, but then I added an additional call after triggering the event that logs the sending of the event to my database. To my surprise, the events so far *always* get logged to my database, but they still sometimes don't show up in analytics. This is the code that does this:

```
                    const event = {
                        'event': 'purchase',
                        'ecommerce': {
                            'transaction_id': orderData.id,
                            'value': orderData.price,
                            'currency': 'EUR',
                            'coupon': orderData.CouponCode,
                            "items": orderData.services.map(elem => ({
                                'item_id': elem.id,
                                'item_name': elem.name,
                                'price': elem.price,
                                'item_type': elem.type,
                                'quantity': 1,
                            })),
                        }
                    };
                    
                    // Send GA4 purchase event
                    dataLayer.push(event);
                    
                    // Log to my db
                    fetch("/ajax/trackAnalytics", {
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            event,
                            cleaning_id: orderData.id
                        })
                    })
```

Let's take the 2nd of December as an example. According to google analytics these were the incoming purchases:

[image: Google analytics data]

But in my database I received the following logs (I redacted the "items" field because it contained customer information but it shouldn't matter):

```
{
   "event":"purchase",
   "ecommerce":{
      "transaction_id":6520,
      "value":73.89,
      "currency":"EUR",
      "coupon":null
   },
   "timestamp":"2022-12-02T15:10:47+00:00"
}

{
   "event":"purchase",
   "ecommerce":{
      "transaction_id":6519,
      "value":67.99,
      "currency":"EUR",
      "coupon":null
   },
   "timestamp":"2022-12-02T15:57:44+00:00"
}

{
   "event":"purchase",
   "ecommerce":{
      "transaction_id":6487,
      "value":197.05,
      "currency":"EUR",
      "coupon":null
   },
   "timestamp":"2022-12-02T19:17:54+00:00"
}
```

As you can see, everything matches up except the transaction with ID 6520.

I tried creating orders that contained the exact elements 6520 did but I wasn't able to reproduce the issue that way. I also tried doing the same with a tracker blocker enabled on my browser but still the data came through.

The tag manager setup is the following:

Purchase trigger:
[image: purchase trigger GTM]

Purchase tag:
[image: Purchase tag GTM]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Darrellwan suggested, adding the line `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];` before `dataLayer.push` seems to have solved the problem, but it's not 100% clear.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes if the user installed the ad block extension on their browser.

These kind of the analytic tags will not fire at all.

You said you tried installed some kind of this and it will work. This mean you might installed the different blocker as the user's.

Not every kind of blocker will block GA request. But still some of them did.

---

There are still many reasons cause the GA4 hit not sent. But if we are using the client side GTM container. It will always have some different with backend data. Just more or less.

Comment: Way more transactions are dopped then I think would be reasonable because of blockers. I already use a browser with a built-in blocker which is already rare, and even so the events go through. More serious blockers should be even rarer, and yet a good third of all events are dropped.

Comment: So if we want to investigate this on other angle. It might be how early this script will run. It is safer to use `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; window.dataLayer.push(event)` Make sure the dataLayer is already exist or initialize the array first.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what solved it, but it has been working correctly for quite a few days now. Maybe it was the `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []`, although my adding that line doesn't exactly coincide with the fixing of the problem.